# Error of scope in VueJS project & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a an error in a VueJS project with TypeScript where my vue files are splitted in HTML, CSS, TS and vue.

I have this error : *Property '$router' does not exist on type '{ validate(): void; }'*

Here is how my files are splitted :

**Login.vue :**

```
<template src="./Login.html"></template>
<script src="./Login.ts"></script>
<style src="./Login.css"></style>
```

**Login.html :**

```
<div id="form" align="center" justify="center">

  <v-col sm="4" align="center" justify="center">
    <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
      <v-text-field v-model="login" :label="$t('Username')" required></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field v-model="password" :label="$t('Password')" type="password" required></v-text-field>

      <v-btn color=primary class="mr-4" @click="validate">
        {{ $t('Login') }}
      </v-btn>

    </v-form>
  </v-col>
</div>
```

**Login.ts :**

```
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    data() {
        return {
            fields: {
                login: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            if ("admin" === this.login && "admin" === this.password) {
                this.$router.push('index')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So with this error, I cannot build my app.

Do someone have any idea ?

Thank you !

Antoine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get types inference you should create the component using `Vue.extend({})` :

**Login.ts**

```
import Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Login',
    data() {
        return {
            fields: {
                login: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            if ("admin" === this.fields.login && "admin" === this.fields.password) {
                this.$router.push('index')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Also, we can use `defineComponent` instead of `Vue.extend` if we're using **Vue 3**. I had the same problem and it helped me