# TypeScript error in my Vue component: TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type '{ myFunction(): void; }'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a Vue2 component that I want to place inside another Vue 2 component. I have created the component inside a TypeScript file.

```js
const ChildrenAgeDropdown = {
  props: ["option"],
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false as boolean,
      options: arrayFromXToY(0, 11),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(): void {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    },
  },

// ... The rest of the component.
}
```

The code works perfectly and the program doesn't crash.

However, I get the following Typescript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type '{ toggle(): void; }'
```

I don't know why I. As you can see, I have declared the property `isOpen` as a property of the Vue component. What should I do to remove this annoying Typescript Error?

Here is a snapshot of my IDE (WebStorm) with the error:

[image]

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65882661/8172857